# Python regex print list of directory

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, directory

I have a list of directories as a list in python with the following data:

```
/a
/a/b
/a/b/1
/a/b/2
/a/b/3
/a/c
/a/c/1
/a/c/2
/a/c/3
/a/d
/a/d/1
/a/d/2
/f
/f/g
/f/g/h
/f/g/i
/f/g/j
```

And I want display the output in the following format:

```
/a
    /b
        /1
        /2
        /3
    /c
        /1
        /2
        /3
    /d
        /1
        /2
/f
    /g
        /h
        /i
        /j
```

I am using the following python function but it is printing an inconsistent output:

```
def formatVFS(lst):
    for line in lst:
        l1 = list(lst)
        l2 = []
        if re.search(r'^/\w+', line) != None:
            temp = re.search(r'^/\w+', line).group()
            print '\t\t', temp
            for line2 in l1:
                if line2.startswith(temp):
                    lst.remove(line2)
                    line2 = line2.replace(temp, '')
                    if line2!= '':
                        l2.append(line2)
                        print '\t\t\t',line2
            formatVFS(l2)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"it is printing an inconsistent output"_ please include it in your question

Comment: Also side note: `print '\t...` is python2 syntax. [Python 2 reached EOL earlier this year.](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) Unless you have a good reason use Python 2, you should use Python 3.

Comment: I have to use this program in a legacy system. So cannot change the version of Python. The installed version of python is 2.7.5

Comment: That's a good reason to use Python 2 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below program, this searches and replaces `\/\w+` which does not at the end of line, with tab. assuming the folders are in expected order. if not you can sort it prior to display.

```py
import re
l=["/a","/a/b","/a/b/1","/a/b/2","/a/b/3","/a/c","/a/c/1","/a/c/2","/a/c/3","/a/d","/a/d/1","/a/d/2","/f","/f/g","/f/g/h","/f/g/i","/f/g/j"]
for i in l:
    print(re.sub(r"\/\w+(?=\/(?!$))","\t",i))
```

**Output**

```
/a
        /b
                /1
                /2
                /3
        /c
                /1
                /2
                /3
        /d
                /1
                /2
/f
        /g
                /h
                /i
                /j
```

Comment: Thanks @Liju for your answer. The program is running perfectly with the given input but it gives error with this type of data
/
/work
/work/archive
/work/pull
/work/push
/work/autowork
/work/autodone
/work/distribution
/work/distribution/1
/work/distribution/2
/work/distribution/3
/work/distribution/4
/work/distribution/5
/work/distribution/6
/work/distribution/7
/work/distribution/8
/work/distribution/9
/work/distribution/10
/work/trigger

Comment: @FarmanAhmed when you ask for help, it's _always_ a better idea to give _as many relevant details_ as you can. _"It gives such-and-such error at line x"_ or _"it prints abc instead of xyz"_ is _so much better_ than saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: @FarmanAhmed, I have updated the program above. please check.